# When are GCD queues used and when do you know you need them? Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

After reading about Concurrent and Serial queues, sync and async, I think I have an idea about how to create queues and the order they are executed in. My problem is that in any of the tutorials I have seen, none of them actually tell you many use cases. For example:

I have a network manager that uses URLSessions and serializes json to send a request to my api. Does it make sense to wrap it in a `.utility` Queue or in a `.userInitiated` or do I just don't wrap it in a queue.

```
let task = LoginTask(username: username, password: password)

let networkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.messenger.network", 
qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)

networkQueue.async {
    task.dataTask(in: dispatcher) { (user, httpCode, error) in
        self.presenter?.loginUserResponse(user: user, httpCode: httpCode, error: error)
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any guidlines I can follow to know when there is a need to use queues or not because I cant find this information anywhere. I realise apple provides example usage howver it is very vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch queues are used in a multitude of use cases, so it's hard to enumerate them, but two very common use cases are as follows:

1. You have some expensive and/or time-consuming process that you want to run on some thread other than the current thread. Often this is used when you're on the main thread and you want to run something on a background thread.

   A good example of this would be image manipulation, which is a notoriously computationally (and memory) intensive process. So, you'd create a queue for image manipulation and then you'd dispatch each image manipulation task to that queue. You might also dispatch the UI update when it's done back to the main queue (because all UI updates must happen on the main thread). A common pattern would be:

   ```
   imageQueue.async {
       // manipulate the image here

       // when done, update the UI:

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           // update the UI and/or model objects on the main thread
       }
   }
   ```
2. You have some shared resource (it could be a simple variable, it could be some interaction with some other shared resource like a file or database) that you want to synchronize regardless of from which thread to invoke it. This is often part of a broader strategy of making something that is not inherently thread-safe behave in a thread safe manner.

The virtue of dispatch queues is that it greatly simplifies writing multi-threaded code, an otherwise very complicated technology.

The thing is that your example, initiating a network request, already runs the request on a background thread and `URLSession` manages all of this for you, so there's little value in using queues for that.

---

In the interest of full disclosure, there is a surprising of variety of different tools using GCD directly (e.g. dispatch groups or dispatch sources) or indirectly (e.g. operation queues) above and beyond the basic dispatch queues discussed above:

- Dispatch groups: Sometimes you will initiate a series of asynchronous tasks and you want to be notified when they're all done. You can use a dispatch group (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28101212/1271826 for a random example). This eliminates you from needing to keep track of when all of these tasks are done yourself.
- Dispatch "apply" (now called `concurrentPerform`): Sometimes when you're running some massively parallel task, you want to use as many threads as you reasonably can. So `concurrentPerform` lets you effectively perform a `for` loop in parallel, and Apple has optimized it for the number of cores and CPUs your particular device, while not flooding it with too many concurrent tasks at any one time, exhausting the limited number of worker threads. See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949292/1271826 for an example of running a `for` loop in parallel.
- Dispatch sources:

  - For example, if you have some background task that is doing a lot of work and you want to update the UI with the progress, sometimes those UI updates can come more quickly than the UI can handle them. So you can use a dispatch source (a `DispatchSourceUserDataAdd`) to decouple the background process from the UI updates. See aforementioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949292/1271826 for an example.
  - Traditionally, a `Timer` runs on the main run loop. But sometimes you want to run it on a background thread, but doing that with a `Timer` is complicated. But you can use a `DispatchSourceTimer` (a GCD timer) to run a timer on a queue other than the main queue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164203/1271826 for example of how to create and use a dispatch timer. Dispatch timers also can be used to avoid some of the strong reference cycles that are easily introduced with `target`-based `Timer` objects.
- Barriers: Sometimes when using a concurrent queue, you want most things to run concurrently, but for other things to run serially with respect to everything else on the queue. A barrier is a way to say "add this task to the queue, but make sure it doesn't run concurrently with respect to anything else on that queue."

  An example of a barrier is the reader-writer pattern, where reading from some memory resource can happen concurrently with respect to all other reads, but any writes must not happen concurrently with respect to anything else on the queue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784770/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628393/1271826.
- Dispatch semaphores: Sometimes you need to let two tasks running on separate threads communicate to each other. You can use semaphores for one thread to "wait" for the "signal" from another.

  One common application of semaphores is to make an inherently asynchronous task behave in a more synchronous manner.

  ```
  networkQueue.async {
      let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(0)
      let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
          // process the response

          // when done, signal that we're done
          semaphore.signal()
      }
      task.resume()
      semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
  }
  ```

  The virtue of this approach is that the dispatched task won't finish until the asynchronous network request is done. So if you needed to issue a series of network requests, but not have them run concurrently, semaphores can accomplish that.

  Semaphores should be used sparingly, though, because they're inherently inefficient (generally blocking one thread waiting for another). Also, make sure you never `wait` for a semaphore from the main thread (because you're defeating the purpose of having the asynchronous task). That's why in the above example, I'm waiting on the `networkQueue`, not the main queue. All of this having been said, there's often better techniques than semaphores, but it is sometimes useful.
- Operation queues: Operation queues are built on top of GCD dispatch queues, but offer some interesting advantages including:

  - The ability to wrap an inherently asynchronous task in a custom `Operation` subclass. (This avoids the disadvantages of the semaphore technique I discussed earlier.) Dispatch queues are generally used when running inherently synchronous tasks on a background thread, but sometimes you want to manage a bunch of tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous. A common example is the wrapping of asynchronous network requests in `Operation` subclass.
  - The ability to easily control the degree of concurrency. Dispatch queues can be either serial or concurrent, but it's cumbersome to design the control mechanism to, for example, to say "run the queued tasks concurrent with respect to each other, but no more than four at any given time." Operation queues make this much easier with the use of `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022598/1271826 for an example.)
  - The ability to establish dependencies between various tasks (e.g. you might have a queue for downloading images and another queue for manipulating the images). With operation queues you can have one operation for the downloading of an image and another for the processing of the image, and you can make the latter dependent upon the completion of the former.

---

There are lots of other GCD related applications and technologies, but these are a few that I use with some frequency.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for a great answer, it really helped me to discover the strengths of dispatch queue. I'm currently working to implement semaphores that should be both inter process and inter thread (meaning that several processes - each has several threads that may use this semaphore). So far the best out-of-the-box solution I've found is using `sem_open` API.. Do you think it would be possible to use dispatch queue (or perhaps XPC) to achieve this goal ? (the API I need for the semaphore is wait and signal of course).